# c# interact html maybe php and javascript with wpf applications

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, html, browser

Hey there maybe my question would be silly.My point is not embedding a html page or something with webbrowser object. Think about a css styled wpf application and buttons with wpf events. something like Steam Client(valve) or League of Legends(pvp.net) client or the most precious maybe some of you knows ijji.com, the ijji reactor that for the best example for my question.

for short version : i want to implement html codes like wpf objects divs,tables etc, and jquery animations like notify plugin or ajax. Maybe i dont even need them and my point is really pointless can you please help me about this ? maybe show me the way ? is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. HTML/CSS and WPF are completely separate technologies. You mentioned that you did not want to embed a webpage, but that is exactly what the steam client does. The store page is an embedded view of the store page on the web.

What you can do is render a UI using HTML/CSS and have it interact with the rest of your program using javascript, through a tool like [awesomium](http://awesomium.codeplex.com/). That has a buit in WPF control to make integration simpler.

Hope this helps.